# Is there a shortcut for creating a python chunk in r studio?

Tags: r-markdown

To insert an r chunk in an r-markdown, you can use the shortcut ctrl + alt + I (windows). Is there a similar shortcut to insert a python chunk?

Comment: No, because python is not the first-class citizen in Rstudio.

Answer (score 14):

please go to tools > Modify Keyboard shortcuts > search using the keyword 'chunk' > then modify the shortcut with your desired shortcut

Comment: Works like a charm; I set it for `Alt+Cmd+P`, but had to modify the shortcut for previous chunk  for R.